# What is the meaning of "13579 vs U"?

Tags: rebus

What is the meaning of the following characters?

> 13579 vs U

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is it

> "you against all odds"?

because
1,3,5,7,9

> all odd numbers

U

> you

Comment: More likely "the odds are against you" given the order.